# Reflection type and value in Go

Tags: reflection, go

I'm not very clear about what this code snippet behaves.

```
func show(i interface{}) {
    switch t := i.(type) {
    case *Person:
      t := reflect.TypeOf(i)  //what t contains?   
      v := reflect.ValueOf(i)  //what v contains?
      tag := t.Elem().Field(0).Tag
      name := v.Elem().Field(0).String() 
    }
}
```

What is the difference between the type and value in reflection?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`reflect.TypeOf()` returns a [reflect.Type](http://golang.org/pkg/reflect/#Type) and `reflect.ValueOf()` returns a [reflect.Value](http://golang.org/pkg/reflect/#Value). A `reflect.Type` allows you to query information that is tied to all variables with the same type while `reflect.Value` allows you to query information and preform operations on data of an arbitrary type.

Also `reflect.ValueOf(i).Type()` is equivalent to `reflect.TypeOf(i)`.

In the example above, you are using the `reflect.Type` to get the "tag" of the first field in the Person struct. You start out with the Type for `*Person`. To get the type information of `Person`, you used `t.Elem()`. Then you pulled the tag information about the first field using `.Field(0).Tag`. The actual value you passed, `i`, does not matter because the Tag of the first field is part of the type.

You used `reflect.Value` to get a string representation of the first field of the value `i`. First you used `v.Elem()` to get a Value for the struct pointed to by `i`, then accessed the first Field's data (`.Field(0)`), and finally turned that data into a string (`.String()`).

Comment: You should also read the [laws of reflection blog post](http://blog.golang.org/2011/09/laws-of-reflection.html) for further details on reflection.